# Why does my crypto.createHmac() generate a different HMAC for the same input?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, hmac, cryptojs

I am trying to match the HMAC in Node.js to the HMAC in PHP for API authorization. The problem is in Node.js, the createHmac() function generates a different HMAC for the same input, and therefore does not match with the HMAC in PHP.

Here is my JS code:

```
events: {
  proxyReq: (proxyReq, req) => {
    const API_KEY = 125;
    const API_SECRET_KEY = 'abc';

    let hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', API_SECRET_KEY);
    hmac.update('0');
    const s = hmac.digest('base64');

    proxyReq.setHeader('x-api-key', API_KEY);
    proxyReq.setHeader('x-api-signature', s);
    proxyReq.setHeader('x-api-date', date);
  },
```

PHP:

```
$API_SECRET_KEY = 'abc';
$client_signature = $request->header('x-api-signature');
$hmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha512', '0', base64_decode($API_SECRET_KEY), true));

Log::error($client_signature);
Log::error($hmac);
```

Latest outputs:

```
[2018-07-11 15:25:28] local.ERROR: dO50o/LcS0/UOXOu/5lHbOMXLe+l225vUU13fWEHeOoUHV7SlcSOE9rQq2UhTlys5N6C4hkq8QTALnpRehtlCg==  
[2018-07-11 15:25:28] local.ERROR: 7W2U/3uEKIMD0s39jmZLlJItwTcSSDQdW7WTYdslvIjuUeGydyqwwAuZzaMP0Do5v1zRJxmPITFdy4EHTY5r6A==  

[2018-07-11 15:25:33] local.ERROR: UYsXZFyoAB2zELZzwjWyktPEHlYqIP3cgLeb/LXK0X8pnkVxiqEaFWK7c1YIWd6hFPpZHn5j1YdbDhpAL7hQ5A==  
[2018-07-11 15:25:33] local.ERROR: 7W2U/3uEKIMD0s39jmZLlJItwTcSSDQdW7WTYdslvIjuUeGydyqwwAuZzaMP0Do5v1zRJxmPITFdy4EHTY5r6A==
```

Any alternatives or solutions would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the HMAC's? And post the HMAC code what you using in PHP?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, just added them

Comment: in your PHP code use base64 in your Node.js code you don't use that ..

Comment: I changed it, yet even with hmac.digest('base64') there is a different hmac generated each time it is run

Answer (score 1):

If you match what you do in PHP with `base64_decode`, you get the correct value:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const API_SECRET_KEY = Buffer.from('abc', 'base64');

let hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', API_SECRET_KEY);
hmac.update('0');
const s = hmac.digest('base64');
console.log(s);
```

`7W2U/3uEKIMD0s39jmZLlJItwTcSSDQdW7WTYdslvIjuUeGydyqwwAuZzaMP0Do5v1zRJxmPITFdy4EHTY5r6A==`

https://repl.it/repls/BouncyBogusGigabyte

Check that you really have the correct constant API_SECRET_KEY value, the correct data input value ('0' in this case), and you are looking at the correct requests in the PHP code. If you provide the same inputs, both libraries will give you the same output value.